How to make the forward slash in a fraction bigger?
I'm writing an inline math equation. But I find that the forward slash in the fraction is a bit small. How can I make it bigger?
The codes is the following:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

The new payoff function for player $i$ is: $\left. {u_i} \right|_{x_i = \alpha_i \left(2 - {\sigma _i^n} / \sigma \right)} = \frac{3\alpha_i-\sigma}{2\alpha_i-1}$.

\end{document}

The output is:

As shown in the above figure, the forward slash / between \sigma _i^n and \sigma looks a bit small. How to make it bigger to make the fraction more elegant?
Any answer or comments are welcome.

The / symbol's size is fine. It's the ( and ) symbols that are needlessly and pointlessly large.

@Mico Thanks for your comments. I find an alternative solution: replacing / by \middle /. By doing so, we can increase the size of the forward slash.

This begs the more fundamental question, why did you feel a need to increase the size of the round parentheses?

@Mico I want to use \left( and \right), because this can automatically change the size of the parentheses according to the inline math equation.

Using \left and \right in the way you propose can have several significant drawbacks. For a longer discussion of this matter, please see the postings Is it ever bad to use \left and \right? and Best practice: How to correctly size the delimiters/fences of the following examples? [Shameless self-citation alert: I'm one of the answer providers for both postings]

The round parentheses are needlessly and pointlessly large. To fix the appearance of the formula, I would not increase the size of the fraction slash symbol, /, as well. Instead, I would reduce the size of the round parentheses by getting rid of the \left and \right sizing directives in _{x_i = \alpha_i \left(2 - {\sigma _i^n} / \sigma \right)}.
Separately, I would increase the size of the vertical bar after u_i by replacing the ineffectual \left. ... \right| construct with \big|.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{\texttt{before}}

\dots for player $i$ is 
$\left. {u_i} \right|_{x_i = \alpha_i \left(2 - {\sigma _i^n} / \sigma \right)} = \frac{3\alpha_i-\sigma}{2\alpha_i-1}$

\bigskip
\textcolor{red}{\texttt{after}}

\dots for player $i$ is 
$u_i\big|_{x_i = \alpha_i (2 - \sigma _i^n / \sigma )} 
= \frac{3\alpha_i-\sigma}{2\alpha_i-1}$

\end{document}

